# Connect to online mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql

I have an online mysql database and I want to connect to it using a java application, but I want to know how to get the name of the host form cPanel.
I have used two names but still can't connect to the database:
The first name I took it from here:
[image]

In the second time I tried to get the server's IP adress from here:
[image]

But I always get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
```

Comment: is port number/ip correct?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai) post it will help

Comment: The problem that I don't know if I'm getting the host name from the right place or I should take from another place.